# Sending asynchronous message from server to client

Tags: c#, asynchronous, distributed, message-passing

I am writing program to solve the dining philosophers problem without a server. It should work by message passing. My application should run 5 times and then connect to each other and solve the problem by themselves. I put a server side and client side in each app, and I  gave them a port number. This image will show what i am talking about:

https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=500223105218

All I want is sending messages between client sides and server sides.

But I have an error in sending message asynchronously from server side by socket handler.(mentioned it below)

I searched about that but could not find any code similar, so how can I send messages directly from server side to client side?

And, how is my idea? is that right? or it is wrong.

This is part of my code which works well:

```
  String status = "Thinking";
        Boolean right = false;
        Boolean left = false;
        // Receiving byte array  
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        SocketPermission permission;
        Socket sListener;
        Socket sListener1;
        Socket sListener2;
        Socket sListener3;
        Socket sListener4;
        Socket handler1;
        Socket handler2;
        Socket handler3;
        Socket handler4;
        Socket handler5;
        Socket senderSock;
        Socket senderSock1;
        Socket senderSock2;
        Socket senderSock3;
        Socket senderSock4;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //start button
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint=null;
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint1=null;
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint2 = null;
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint3 = null;
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint4 = null;
                // Creates one SocketPermission object for access restrictions
                permission = new SocketPermission(
                NetworkAccess.Accept,     // Allowed to accept connections 
                TransportType.Tcp,        // Defines transport types 
                "",                       // The IP addresses of local host 
                SocketPermission.AllPorts // Specifies all ports 
                );

                // Listening Socket object 
                sListener = null;
                sListener1 = null;
                sListener2 = null;
                sListener3 = null;
                sListener4 = null;
                // Ensures the code to have permission to access a Socket 
                permission.Demand();

                // Resolves a host name to an IPHostEntry instance 
                IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("");

                // Gets first IP address associated with a localhost 
                IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];

                // Creates a network endpoint 
                if (Sport.Text == "1000")
                {
                    ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, Convert.ToInt32(Sport.Text));
                }else if (Sport.Text == "1001")
                {
                    ipEndPoint1 = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, Convert.ToInt32(Sport.Text));
                }
                else if (Sport.Text == "1002")
                {
                    ipEndPoint2 = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, Convert.ToInt32(Sport.Text));
                }
                else if (Sport.Text == "1003")
                {
                    ipEndPoint3 = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, Convert.ToInt32(Sport.Text));
                }
                else if (Sport.Text == "1004")
                {
                    ipEndPoint4 = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, Convert.ToInt32(Sport.Text));
                }

                // Associates a Socket with a local endpoint                              
                if (Sport.Text == "1000")
                {
                    // Create one Socket object to listen the incoming connection 
                    sListener = new Socket(
                    ipAddr.AddressFamily,
                    SocketType.Stream,
                    ProtocolType.Tcp
                    );
                    sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
                    sListener.Listen(10);
                }else if(Sport.Text == "1001")
                {
                    sListener1 = new Socket(
                    ipAddr.AddressFamily,
                    SocketType.Stream,
                    ProtocolType.Tcp
                    );
                    sListener1.Bind(ipEndPoint1);
                    sListener1.Listen(10);
                }
                else if (Sport.Text == "1002")
                {
                    sListener2 = new Socket(
                    ipAddr.AddressFamily,
                    SocketType.Stream,
                    ProtocolType.Tcp
                    );
                    sListener2.Bind(ipEndPoint2);
                    sListener2.Listen(10);
                }
                else if (Sport.Text == "1003")
                {
                    sListener3 = new Socket(
                   ipAddr.AddressFamily,
                   SocketType.Stream,
                   ProtocolType.Tcp
                   );
                    sListener3.Bind(ipEndPoint3);
                    sListener3.Listen(10);
                }
                else if (Sport.Text == "1004")
                {
                    sListener4 = new Socket(
                    ipAddr.AddressFamily,
                    SocketType.Stream,
                    ProtocolType.Tcp
                    );
                    sListener4.Bind(ipEndPoint4);
                    sListener4.Listen(10);
                }

                label3.Text = "Server started.";
                statusLabel.Text = "READY";
                button1.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString()); }
        }


        //connect button
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = null;
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint1 = null;
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint2 = null;
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint3 = null;
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint4 = null;
                // Create one SocketPermission for socket access restrictions 
                SocketPermission permission = new SocketPermission(
                    NetworkAccess.Connect,    // Connection permission 
                    TransportType.Tcp,        // Defines transport types 
                    "",                       // Gets the IP addresses 
                    SocketPermission.AllPorts // All ports 
                    );

                // Ensures the code to have permission to access a Socket 
                permission.Demand();

                // Resolves a host name to an IPHostEntry instance            
                IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("");

                // Gets first IP address associated with a localhost 

                IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];

                // Creates a network endpoint 
                if (Cport.Text == "1000")
                {
                     ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, Convert.ToInt32(Cport.Text));
                }else if (Cport.Text == "1001")
                {
                     ipEndPoint1 = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, Convert.ToInt32(Cport.Text));
                }
                else if (Cport.Text == "1002")
                {
                     ipEndPoint2 = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, Convert.ToInt32(Cport.Text));
                }
                else if (Cport.Text == "1003")
                {
                     ipEndPoint3 = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, Convert.ToInt32(Cport.Text));
                }
                else if (Cport.Text == "1004")
                {
                     ipEndPoint4 = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, Convert.ToInt32(Cport.Text));
                }


                if (Cport.Text == "1000")//A
                {
                    // Create one Socket object to setup Tcp connection 
                    senderSock = new Socket(
                        ipAddr.AddressFamily,// Specifies the addressing scheme 
                        SocketType.Stream,   // The type of socket  
                        ProtocolType.Tcp     // Specifies the protocols  
                        );
                    senderSock.NoDelay = false;   // Using the Nagle algorithm 
                    // Establishes a connection to a remote host 
                    senderSock.Connect(ipEndPoint);
                    statusLabel.Text = "Socket connected to " + senderSock.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                }
                else if (Cport.Text == "1001")//B
                {
                    senderSock1 = new Socket(
                        ipAddr.AddressFamily,
                        SocketType.Stream,    
                        ProtocolType.Tcp    
                        );
                    senderSock1.NoDelay = false;   
                    senderSock1.Connect(ipEndPoint1);
                    statusLabel.Text = "Socket connected to " + senderSock1.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                }
                else if (Cport.Text == "1002")//C
                {
                    senderSock2 = new Socket(
                        ipAddr.AddressFamily,
                        SocketType.Stream,
                        ProtocolType.Tcp
                        );
                    senderSock2.NoDelay = false;
                    senderSock2.Connect(ipEndPoint2);
                    statusLabel.Text = "Socket connected to " + senderSock2.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                }
                else if (Cport.Text == "1003")//D
                {
                    senderSock3 = new Socket(
                        ipAddr.AddressFamily,
                        SocketType.Stream,
                        ProtocolType.Tcp
                        );
                    senderSock3.NoDelay = false;
                    senderSock3.Connect(ipEndPoint3);
                    statusLabel.Text = "Socket connected to " + senderSock3.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                }
                else if (Cport.Text == "1004")//E
                {
                    senderSock4 = new Socket(
                        ipAddr.AddressFamily,
                        SocketType.Stream,
                        ProtocolType.Tcp
                        );
                    senderSock4.NoDelay = false;
                    senderSock4.Connect(ipEndPoint4);
                    statusLabel.Text = "Socket connected to " + senderSock4.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                }
               button2.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString()); }

            label3.Text = "wait...";
            Thread.Sleep(4000);
            send_st();
        }
```

And here is my code where I get an Error in "Send(handler1, status);"
The error is: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
//send status from clnt to server
        public void sendCToS(String str)
        {
            try
            {
                // Sending message 
                //<Client Quit> is the sign for end of data 
                byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str + "<Client Quit>");
                // Sends data to a connected Socket. 
                //send status from client to server
                int bytesSend = senderSock.Send(msg);//receiver server tasmim giri va response send mikone

            }
            catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString()); }
        }

        //it send hungry status from both to both!
        public void send_st()
        {
            // Resolves a host name to an IPHostEntry instance 
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("");
            // Gets first IP address associated with a localhost 
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int delay = rnd.Next(2000, 5000);
            while (true)
            {
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                statusLabel.Text = status;
                statusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                Thread.Sleep(delay);

                if (Sport.Text == "1000")//A
                {
                    status = "hungry";
                    statusLabel.Text = "HUNGRY";
                    statusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    //send status from server to clint
                    Send(handler1, status);                  
                    //send status from clnt to server
                    sendCToS(status);                   
                    label3.Text = "status Sent to left and right";
                }
                else if (Sport.Text == "1001")//B
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    status = "hungry";
                    statusLabel.Text = "HUNGRY";
                    statusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    //send status from server to clint
                    Send(handler2, status);
                    //send status from clnt to server
                    sendCToS(status);
                    label3.Text = "status Sent to left and right";
                }
                else if (Sport.Text == "1002")//C
                {
                    status = "hungry";
                    statusLabel.Text = "HUNGRY";
                    statusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    //send status from server to clint
                    Send(handler3, status);
                    //send status from clnt to server
                    sendCToS(status);
                    label3.Text = "status Sent to left and right";
                }
                else if (Sport.Text == "1003")//D
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    status = "hungry";
                    statusLabel.Text = "HUNGRY";
                    statusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    //send status from server to clint
                    Send(handler4, status);
                    //send status from clnt to server
                    sendCToS(status);
                    label3.Text = "status Sent to left and right";
                }
                else if (Sport.Text == "1004")//E
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    status = "hungry";
                    statusLabel.Text = "HUNGRY";
                    statusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    //send status from server to clint
                    Send(handler5, status);
                    //send status from clnt to server
                    sendCToS(status);
                    label3.Text = "status Sent to left and right";
                }

            }
        }

        //server side
        // Thread signal.
        public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket listener = null;
            // A new Socket to handle remote host communication 
            Socket handler = null;
            try
            {
                // Receiving byte array 
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                // Get Listening Socket object 
                listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                // Create a new socket 
                handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

                // Using the Nagle algorithm 
                handler.NoDelay = false;

                StateObject state = new StateObject();

                // Begins to asynchronously receive data 
                handler.BeginReceive(
                    buffer,        // An array of type Byt for received data 
                    0,             // The zero-based position in the buffer  
                    buffer.Length, // The number of bytes to receive 
                    0,// Specifies send and receive behaviors 
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback),//An AsyncCallback delegate 
                    state            // Specifies infomation for receive operation 
                    );

            }
            catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString()); }
        }

        public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            String response = "ok";
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
                // from the asynchronous state object.
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket handler = state.workSocket;

                // Read data from the client socket. 
                int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

                // Received message 
                string content = string.Empty;

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                        state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                    // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
                    // more data.
                    content = state.sb.ToString();
                    if (content.IndexOf("<Client Quit>") > -1)
                    {
                        // All the data has been read from the client
                        label3.Text = content;
                    }
                    else {
                        // Not all data received. Get more.
                        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0,StateObject.BufferSize, 0, 
                        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                    }
```

And this is the rest of the server side functions:

```
//func for echo back to client
        private void Send(Socket handler, String data)
        {
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
        }

        public void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {

            try
            {
                // A Socket which has sent the data to remote host 
                Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                // The number of bytes sent to the Socket 
                int bytesSend = handler.EndSend(ar);
                label3.Text = "Sent {0} bytes to Client" + bytesSend;
            }
            catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString()); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive the problem is with this line:
senderSock.Send(msg);

You never instantiated the senderSock, you only declared it.
try this:

```
 senderSock= new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
senderSock.Send(msg);
```

Comment: This is the details:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at philoV3.Form1.Send(Socket handler, String data) in C:\Users\sara\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\philoV3\philoV3\Form1.cs:line 538